# Firestore query not receving updates on create new doc

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore query and, I need it to listen to the creation of new documents, I tried many possibilities but couldn't make it work, every time I create a document the listener is not triggered. This is my listener code:

```
firestore
        .collection("users")
        .document("123")
        .collection("images")
        .whereField("postId", isEqualTo: "123")
        .order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
        .limit(to: 1)
        .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] snapshot, error in
            guard let imageDocument = snapshot?.documents.first else {
                return
            }
            // this print statement is only being called once (not being called when creating a new doc)
            print(imageDocument)
        }
...
```

And this is my query to create the document:

```
firestore
    .collection("users")
    .document("123")
    .collection("images")
    .document()
    .setData([
        "postId": "123",
        "imageUrl": "....",
        "createdAt": Timestamp()
    ]) { error in
       guard let error = error else { return }
       print(error)
    }
```

My goal is that this listener is triggered when I create a new document in the Firestore.

Also, if I remove the limit from my listener query, the code works, but I will spend a lot of reads unnecessarily.

Comment: Is it possible that you're not creating the document in the tree you're describing? IE inside the "users" collection, "123" document, "images" collection, etc.

Comment: @jnpdx nope, I'm creating correctly. If I remove the limit, order it ascending and get the last document, it works fine, but I don't want to spend firestore reads unnecessarily.

Comment: Please edit your question to also show the minimal closer/completion handler with which you have the problem. At its least `print` the values, and show us the updated code and its problematic output. It'd probably also help if we could see the code that writes the document you expect to see inside the query, here too with all values hardcoded just like you (yay ) did in the query.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, I appreciate your attention. I updated the question with the creation query, hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm.... I don't immediately see what could go wrong there. I hope somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: In your snapshot listener, remove the guard statement and print the entire snapshot and any errors. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about the way you are adding data to Firestore, but how you reading it. There is nothing related to the "limit(to: 1)" call either. When you perform the following query:

```
firestore
    .collection("users")
    .document("123")
    .collection("images")
    .whereField("postId", isEqualTo: "123")
    .order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
    .limit(to: 1)
```

It means that you want to get all documents from the "images" sub-collection where the "postId" field holds the value of "123", and right after that, you order the results according to the "createdAt" field descending and limit the result to "1".

To be able to make such a query work, you have to create an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for it, otherwise, it won't return any results. You can create the required index manually in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/):

[image]

Or you'll find in your IDE a message that looks like this:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...
```

You can simply click on that link or copy and paste the URL into a web browser and your index will be created automatically for you.

The code should remain unchanged.

Comment: Hi Vitor. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hey there, it worked!! My index was with both fields Ascending, changing the createdAt to Descending made the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have `limit(to: 1)` in your query. Try removing it.

Comment: It works if I remove the limit, but I don't want to spend firestore reads unnecessarily.